# Display Google Maps with current position with ngMap

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, typescript

I'm trying to display a Google Maps webpage with a marker that shows the current position (using this library -> https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps). This is the controller.

```
export class SearchCtrl implements ISearchCtrl {
    longitude: number;
    latitude: number;

    constructor(public StartLoadingService: IStartLoadingService,
                public LoginService: ILoginService,
                public NgMap) {

        this.longitude = 9.191383;
        this.latitude =  45.464211;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setLocations.bind(this));
    }

    setLocations(position): void {
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    }
}
```

Is there a function I can call on NgMap to put a marker and jump to such position?

Thanks,

Nano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose you could specify `current-location` for `position` attribute and set `centered` to `true`:

```
<marker centered="true" position="current-location" ></marker>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/eVz9M7HUXK4ItWTqpcIk?p=preview)